# Comparing two outputs with plotting in R

Tags: r, plot

How to plot two or more columns of a data frame in a graph with a different colors in R?

With Matlab, it is very easy but I am confused with R.
Matlab code:

```
figure ()
data = csvread('output.csv',1,0);
iteration = data (:,1);
calc= data(:,2);
optimal = data(:,3);
plot (iteration,calc,'k',iteration,optimal,'bl')
title ('outputs Vs. Data Point');
xlabel('Data Point');
ylabel('output');
```

Comment: Please provide some or all of `output.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot your first data set with plot() and then add the second data set with points()

```
iteration <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
calc <- c(1,4,7,9,4,6)
optimal <- c(6,8,3,6,7,6)

plot(iteration,calc,type="p",col="red")
points(iteration,optimal,col="green")
```

EDIT: to create the same with ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=iteration, y=calc))+
geom_point(aes(color="red"))+
geom_point(aes(y=optimal, color="green"))
```

with ggplot2 you have more options to improve your plot design. Without more specification how a "beautiful plot" should look like, I can't help you ;)

Comment: Thanks, what about plotting with ggplot2? I mean is there anyway to make the plot more beautiful?